# How can I integrate Dropbox with PCManFM?

Tags: dropbox, lubuntu, filemanager, lxde

I'm using Lubuntu 11.04 and I installed Dropbox.

Every time I click on the tray icon, Dropbox opens Chrome to show my files.

How to change this behaviour? It would be nice to open my files from the tray with the regular file manager (PCManFM).

Comment: Not sure if Ask Ubuntu is the best place to ask support for Dropbox - use their forums instead!

Comment: Isn't there an option when you rightclick: "Open Dropbox Folder"

Comment: @Syzygy - "Open Dropbox Folder" opens the dropbox folder in Chromium.

Comment: @Papukaija - Asking about Dropbox here isn't really any different than asking about PHP, Chrome, PyQT, VLC, or any other application (all of which have been asked about; for that matter, there's a Dropbox *tag*). Also, the question refers to Dropbox's behavior as it relates to Ubuntu with LXDE.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Install `libfile-mimeinfo-perl` from the repository
2. Run (in terminal) `mimeopen -d ~/Desktop` (any folder can be used)
3. mimeopen should prompt you to pick something to open it with. For me, PCManFM was the first option. Select the option that lists PCManFM.
4. Open Dropbox from the system tray. It should now open in PCManFM.

Comment: Shauna - excellent answer.  This one always has always puzzled me.  Well done :)

Comment: Glad I could help. :) I was having the same issue. I finally got annoyed enough to do some digging and experimenting.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that it works as well this way. This goes only for Firefox users.

1. Install Firefox
2. Click on the LXDE Menu Button down left in the screen --> Preferences --> Default Programs
3. Change the default browser from Chromium to Firefox
4. Open the Dropbox folder from the system tray. It should now open in PCManFM

Answer (score 0):

I'm running KUbuntu, and for me the answer was to start `System center`, choose `Default applications` and `File manager`. There the default behaviour was to run mount. Not usfull to me. Changed it to Dolphin, and now it works.