# Which file managers support Dropbox status icons?

Tags: icons, filemanager, dropbox

I would like to play around with file mangers other than Nautilus, but recall from years ago that far from all support the Dropbox status icons.

As I frequently orientate myself by those icons to check if a given file or folder has synced, support for them is high on my list.

So: What file managers support Dropbox status icons, and what is needed to get them to display?

Comment: `apt show dropbox` lists, among other things, plugins to support Dropbox integration with *caja* and *thunar*. I know that [Dolphin](https://askubuntu.com/a/949139/248158) also supports Dropbox. PCManFM, now comes in two flavors, gtk and LXQt: [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/61115/248158) from some years ago, *may* be relevant to the gtk version. BTW, what do you mean by "I frequently orientate myself by those icons" and "What file managers support Dropbox status icons"? I'm asking because, to me,that's more a function of your panel or status bar and not the file manager.

Comment: Good point. I updated and hope that it makes it clear. To me, the file manager status icons provide more information than the sync status in the panel, as the latter merely tells you e.g. that something is still to sync, not what it is.

Answer (score 1):

To get Dropbox icons on **Caja file manager** (fork of Nautilus) you have to install [`caja-dropbox`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/caja-dropbox) package:

```
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo apt-get install caja-dropbox
```

Then logout (or reboot) and login back.
As the result you will get icons in Caja and Dropbox icon on GNOME or MATE panel.
See screenshot below from Ubuntu MATE:

[image: result of Caja Dropbox package installation]

---

To get Dropbox icons on **Nautilus** you have to install [`nautilus-dropbox`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/nautilus-dropbox) package:

```
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo apt-get install nautilus-dropbox
```

Then logout (or reboot) and login back.
As the result you will get icons in Nautilus and Dropbox icon on GNOME panel.
See screenshot below from GNOME FlashBack session:

[image: result of Nautilus Dropbox package installation]